# Empty CGMutablePathRef paths?

Tags: ios, cgpath, quartz-core

I there a way to remove all paths from CGMutablePathRef and get a clear one ?

I am drawing with a path and I wish to get it empt for reuse ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so, just release it and create a new one - should be faster anyways.

```
CGPathRelease(pathref);
pathref = CGPathCreateMutable();
```